# Mac is constantly scrolling to the right

Tags: macos, mac, scrolling

I have noticed strange behavior since yesterday, which is that on my Mac, the active window is constantly trying to scroll slowly to the right. I have:

- disconnected my mouse (still happens)
- disconnected my keyboard (still happens)
- restarted the computer (still happens)

If a window is active and I move the mouse cursor away from that window (but I can still type in it) the scrolling stops.

What might be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem:

Disconnected all mice (I had a Logitech and Anker connected) and restarted the computer. After restarting, I plugged in one at a time and the issue didn't come back.

Comment: In my case I didn't need to restart computer, I just had to turn the mouse off and on again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a mouse try to disable the trackpad. This work for me.

Comment: This doesn't really fix the issue - it maims the computer to hide it. You should've posted this as a comment, not an answer. Unfortunately you don't have enough reputation yet, but you can gain some by posting useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it appears to be my external mouse driver(LogiTech). Whenever I close the driver's app the issue disappears.

Please read this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1700130/1699749

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).