# Disable smooth scrolling on Logitech M510?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-10, scrolling, logitech-mouse

I recently bought [this](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/wireless-mouse-m510) at a nearby store and noticed that when scrolling slightly up or down, the page slowly moves over a longer period of time. The page will zoom in out if I press Ctrl when I want to open links to another tab. This behavior is persistent across browsers only (does not affect Adobe reader, notepad, etc.).

Is there a way to change the scrolling behavior on Windows 10 so that this mouse does not smooth scroll?

I've already downloaded the required drivers only to find out there is no smooth scrolling option under [Logitech Options](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/options).

Comment: Firefox: go to `about:preferences#advanced` and uncheck `Use smooth scrolling`

Comment: @DavidPostill it's already unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Logitech M330](https://www.logitech.com/products/mice/m330-silent-plus-mouse.910-004905.html) (firmware version 55.4.21) and having the same issue. Smooth scrolling appears in IE, Chrome and Firefox on my Windows 10 21H1, but I don't like it.
After installing [Logitech Options](https://www.logitech.com/software/options.html) (version 9.50.269), I'm able to disable the "smooth scrolling" feature in the following way:

1. Make sure you have connected the mouse to your computer.
2. Open the "Logitech Options" software.
3. Switch to the "Point & Scroll" tab.
4. Now you can see the "Smooth scrolling" option.

Screenshot:

[image: logitech_options-point_and_scroll-smooth_scrolling]

Comment: To add to the answer: it you have configured custom mouse buttons for specific applications, you need to disable smooth scrolling for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the "Logitech Smooth Scrolling" plugin in the Extensions screen of your browser.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/577460)

Comment: @DavidPostill This is how you might be able to turn smooth scrolling off on a Logitech mouse. That's what the question was.

Comment: He says it happens in all browsers so a Chrome plugin cannot be causing it ...

Comment: @DavidPostill The plugin is for Chrome and Internet Explorer, so if that's the only browsers they have installed, this could be the cause.

Comment: The question is tagged Firefox (which doesn't have this plugin).

Comment: @DavidPostill Ouch, didn't see that, sorry!

Comment: No worries. That's why I commented on his question instead of writing my own answer ... :)

Comment: Note also that the OP has deleted their account. I'm going to vote to close the question as  "too broad". It's a poor question

Answer (score 0):

Logitech setpoint settings > scroll tab > scroll options button (at the bottom) > uncheck smooth scrolling box.

Comment: If this option is in the browser extension for Chrome and Internet Explorer it's already been confirmed the author is using Firefox and thus the changing an option in an extension that does not exist for the browser does not actually apply to the author's question.